# How to solve the error "signal has multiple source"?

Tags: asynchronous, vhdl, counter

I am beginner. I need to make 8-bit asynchronous down counter with load using D flop flop in structural description.

I did it without load and it works great but when I am trying this -> `nqdout <= load` I have the error: `signal "nqdout" has multiple source`

How to make the load?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity kur_3 is
    generic(size: positive := 8);
    port(clk, mode, preset: in std_logic;
        load: in std_logic_vector((size-1) downto 0);
        dout: out std_logic_vector((size-1) downto 0));
end kur_3;

architecture struct of kur_3 is
    signal q, nqdout, tmp: std_logic_vector((size-1) downto 0);

    component kur_1 port(d, clk, preset: in std_logic; q, nq: out std_logic); end component;

    begin
        --nqdout <= load;
        a0: for i in (size-1) downto 0 generate 
            b0: if (i = 0) generate
                c0: kur_1 port map (nqdout(i), clk, preset, q(i), nqdout(i));
            end generate;   
            b1: if (i > 0) generate
                c1: kur_1 port map (nqdout(i), q(i-1), preset, q(i), nqdout(i));
            end generate;
        end generate;
        dout <= q;      
    end struct;

configuration con of kur_3 is
    for struct
        for all: 
            kur_1 use entity work.kur_1(beh);
        end for;
    end for;
end con;
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If `load` is supposed to initialize the value of the counter, you might think to use a mux structure that connects the input of each flip flop to either `nqdout` or `load`, depending on a selection signal (is that what `preset` is supposed to do?)

Comment: preset fills DFF with  "1".
Yes, you`re right. 
load is supposed to initialize the value of the counter

Comment: So when is the `load` value supposed to be loaded?

Comment: When preset is 1 it fills counter with 1. (like 11111111)
When preset is 0 I must get value from load and take it in my counter as a start value

Comment: Ok, but how do you define your "start" condition? Can you have a `start` input signal?

Comment: Yes, I have. I forgot  write it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

In the code without `nqdout <= load;` then the `nqout` signal is driven from an output of `c0: kur_1`, som when you add the `nqdout <= load;` the `nqout` signal is driven from two different sources, thus the error from the synthesis tool.

Simulation tools are fine with multiple drives, since the final value of the signal is then determined through resolution function for `std_logic`, but in synthesis there can be only one driver.

So to address you question of how to solve this: Where is the counter state kept?  You want to load a new value into the counter at the location where the state is kept; not just overriding the output value of the counter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `start` input port, you can use it as a selection signal for a mux that selects either the `load` input or the `nqdout` signal as input to the flip-flops.

```
entity kur_3 is
    generic(size: positive := 8);
    port(clk, mode, preset, start: in std_logic;
        load: in std_logic_vector((size-1) downto 0);
        dout: out std_logic_vector((size-1) downto 0));
end kur_3;

architecture struct of kur_3 is
    signal q, nqdout, ff_in: std_logic_vector((size-1) downto 0);

    component kur_1 port(d, clk, preset: in std_logic; q, nq: out std_logic); end component;

    begin
        with start select
           ff_in <= nqdout when '0'
                    load when others;
        a0: for i in (size-1) downto 0 generate 
            b0: if (i = 0) generate
                c0: kur_1 port map (ff_in(i), clk, preset, q(i), nqdout(i));
            end generate;   
            b1: if (i > 0) generate
                c1: kur_1 port map (ff_in(i), q(i-1), preset, q(i), nqdout(i));
            end generate;
        end generate;
        dout <= q;      
    end struct;
```

This allows to have the `load` signal connected to the flip-flops when `start` is high, but I don't know how well this will work with your asynchronous clock structure, as your flip flops will latch the input value only at the rising edge of the output of the previous stage.